# Understanding Microservices and GRPC

Tags: grpc

I have a Python Website and a GRPC service that's going to be written in GO.

I am looking to introduce microservices to the website.

-The GRPC Chat server will be written in GOLANG. The GRPC client would be written in python as my website is python. In future I would like a swift GRPC stub to communicate with this go server as well.

Is this the correct architecture?

**My website current GRPC client**
chat submit button-> python grpc client-> go grpc server -> DB -> gogrpc server->  pygrpc client->UpdateChat

**A request from any languages future mobile GRPC Client**
UpdateChatRequest-> Any GRPC Client -> go GRPC server -> DB -> go GRPC Server -> Any GRPC Client->UpdateChat

Comment: Your question is about an architecture. It is difficult to answer because there are different tradeoffs. Instead I advise to search on internet for this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are intending on building multiple what you may call "gRPC Clients" that talk to the Go gRPC server to perform CRUD operations for chat, this looks like a decent model. I will say that nowadays, a lot of gRPC implementations are used for inter-microservice communication more than they are used for your standard (client -> gateway -> micro-service cluster) client-server comms. In my opinion, this is largely due to gRPC-web not being able to fully operate over HTTP/2. Now, I honesty don't see a problem with implementing gRPC on thick clients (like on native mobile or desktop), because the gRPC can be fully supported in those scenarios, just not in the browser yet.

If you are not using gRPC-web on your front end, it might be worth looking in to. gRPC-web requires a proxy anyways, so you're operating over HTTP/1.1 whether you use gRPC or not until browsers support more directly coupling with HTTP/2.

It is a little unclear, but you arch isn't necessarily screaming micro-services. In reality, it is better not to view the "micro-services" concept as an overnight transition that should take place. Your arch is a monolith right now. Using technologies like gRPC doesn't automatically make your architecture a micro-services architecture, but it does better prepare you for the [gradual transition](https://gotopia.tech/bookclub/episodes/moving-to-microservices-with-sam-newman-and-martin-fowler) you should take to develop your architecture into more of a distributed, service-based model. Of course, the term "micro-service" is often a buzz word with many different scopes of meaning, it is important to know what context you are thinking in.